# Facebook Open Graph stories api v4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im developing an android app and already connected everything to facebook and sucessfully shared a dialog and liked a page. Now i would like to post to feed using open graph api because i wanted to post everything in my own format, a image, title, coordinates and a small description.
Ive already created the custom open graph storie but i cant manage to make this work.
The share dialog opens and closes instantly

Namespace is roteiroobidos

Actiontype is Share

Object type is Interesting_place

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "obidosroteiro.share")
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("obidosroteiro.share") //If i try to change any of these "share" the share dialog would not even open
            .putObject("obidosroteiro:share", object)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("obidosroteiro:share")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
```

Thanks

Comment: any logcat error messages? Are you trying to test this with a developer/admin of the app? can you post a screenshot of how your OG object and action looks like in your app dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the way that you are calling your object/action using : instead of . 
Also the setPreviewPropertyName() should contain the name of your object, in this case share.

Change to this:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "obidosroteiro:share")
            .build();
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("obidosroteiro:share") //If i try to change any of these "share" the share dialog would not even open
            .putObject("obidosroteiro:share", object)
            .build();
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("share")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
```